# DotNet Entity Framework on VSCode Mac -- (Table)Exists() does not exist in current context in Controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I am following along with the dotnet Microsoft tutorial docs. My one disadvantage is that I'm on a Mac using VS Code. At one point in the tutorial there was a scaffolding command that did not work in VS Code. So far, everything else has worked, but I'm wondering if something is missing in my Controller and that is why I am getting this error. I copy and pasted directly from the Docs. Although, the error infers that it is a syntax issue with the try/catch statement. (which I have reviewed and everything looks in order)

Here is my Controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using virus_mvc.Models;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using virus_mvc.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace virus_mvc.Controllers
{
    public class VirusDataController : Controller
    {
       public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.VirusData.ToListAsync());
        }
        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 

        public IActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Hello " + name;
            ViewData["NumTimes"] = numTimes;

            return View();
        }

        // GET: VirusData/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var virus = await _context.VirusData
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (virus == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(virus);
        }

        // GET: Movies/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var virus = await _context.VirusData.FindAsync(id);
            if (virus == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(virus);
        }

     
        // POST: Movies/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] VirusData virus)
        {
            if (id != virus.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(virus);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    **if (!VirusDataExists(virus.Id))** -- this is the line throwing the error
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(virus);
        }
        
    private readonly virus_mvcContext _context;

        public VirusDataController(virus_mvcContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Error:
`/Users/katie/C_sharp/virus_backend/virus_mvc/Controllers/VirusDataController.cs(89,26): error CS0103: The name 'VirusDataExists' does not exist in the current context [/Users/katie/C_sharp/virus_backend/virus_mvc/virus_mvc.csproj]`

Here's my Model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using virus_mvc.Data;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace virus_mvc.Models
{
    public class VirusData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `_context` defined?  Have you verified that you're able to connect to your database?

Comment: the _context I believe is defined from Using virus_mvc.Data; that is inheriting the DBContext. In terms of being connected to my DB...I have been able to seed already and have been able to see all the data displayed. I'm not sure if that counts.

Comment: It had worked before with the _context being listed in previous methods, like Index.

Comment: @KatieClark I haven't looked over your code very carefully, but shouldn't `VirusDataExists` be `VirusData.Exists` instead, i.e., you're missing a "."?

Comment: Hi John, I had earlier thought the same thing. The docs do not include a '.' and when I included a '.' It then tries to look for a method on the VirusData Model. Which the Exists should be coming from the Entity Framework. It's a preexisting method